# Convert asn1 to base64 in C#

Tags: c#, certificate, asn.1, x509certificate2

Is there a way to convert an ASN.1 encoded private key of X509Certificate into Base64 format, using C# code?

Comment: what do you have currently? raw binary? of infoset xml?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Both XmlString and raw bytes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second thought - probably I didn't understood your question on first answer.
If you wanted to convert key data to format similar to .pem files you need to do something similar as in this [article about generating .pem files](https://plus.google.com/103576220004954718227/posts/PBkbJMKPGVL)

Comment: Broken link  :-0

Answer (score 2):

You should try to combine together
[X509Certificate2.PrivateKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx)
and
[RSA.FromXmlString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring.aspx).

I think that you can load data from ASN.1 with RSA.FromXmlString and then set X509Certificate2.PrivateKey property to resulting RSA object. After that you can use one of X509Certificate2 Export() methods to export your key.

If you just need to convert ASN.1 DER encoded key to Base64 (.pem) format, you just need to encode binary byte array to Base64 (with System.Convert.ToBase64String()) and add header/footer for result:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
encoded key data goes here
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Yes, I was aware about this -- but the Export() function exports the whole certificate, and I need the private key only.

Comment: I believe, that if you have byte array of private key, you just need to encode it to base64 (probably with System.Convert.ToBase64String()) and add header and footer to it.